# Is it possible to avoid strict aliasing rule violation in this example?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to avoid the strict aliasing warning `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]` for the example below, without retaining the pointer, that the placement `new` returns, without using any compiler-specific extensions?

```
int main()
{
  alignas(::std::string) char a[sizeof(::std::string)];

  new (a) ::std::string;

  auto& s(*reinterpret_cast<::std::string*>(a));

  return s.size();
}
```

Comment: what is that code ??? what do you want to do ???

Comment: @StephaneRolland Avoid/word around the warning.

Comment: "retaining the pointer, that the placement `new` returns" is exactly how to do it. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: @MikeSeymour because a `variant`-like class can contain several types but containing the pointers to all of the possible types it may contain, may be impractical.

Comment: just for me, what is the meaning of the line `new (a) ::std::string;` ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland [Placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html)

Comment: I find this surprising since aliasing to any pointer can be aliased to any pointer-to-chartype by design (to manipulate raw memory). So the first question I would ask is: *is `-Wstrict-aliasing` worth agonizing over ?*

Comment: @MatthieuM., It's quite weird. It complains with array and not with a pointer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0465a6bd4772f99 Perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: @zch: sounds weird indeed :x

Comment: @zch I've thought about reporting this. Will you?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do it:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  alignas(::std::string) char a[sizeof(::std::string)];

  new (a) ::std::string;

  void* const tmp(a);

  auto& s(*static_cast<::std::string*>(tmp));

  return s.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't do this?

```
  alignas(::std::string) char a[sizeof(::std::string)];

  auto s = new (a) ::std::string;

  return s->size();
```

Comment: Yeah, a `variant` can contain multiple types, storing pointers to all of them is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach below there's no need to store pointers to multiple types.

```
int main()
{
  alignas(::std::string) char a[sizeof(::std::string)];

  char *p = reinterpret_cast<char *> (new (a) ::std::string);

  auto& s(*reinterpret_cast<::std::string*>(p));

  return s.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through a char* temporary seems to avoid the warning:

```
int main()
{
  alignas(::std::string) char a[sizeof(::std::string)];

  new (a) ::std::string;

  char* t = a;
  auto& s(*reinterpret_cast<::std::string*>(t));

  return s.size();
}
```